# Generate numbers that increase at decreasing level

Tags: java

Currently I need to generate 100 increasing numbers between 10 and 280. The increase should be at decreasing level. Here is an example of some numbers that could be in the series:

> 10, 20, 29, ... , 277.8, 279, 280

I really have no idea how to do this, the numbers don't really matter, the important thing is that the first value is 10 and the last value is 280. The other 98 numbers should increase at a decreasing level.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: Find a mathematical function first I would say that given x=1 results in 10, and x=100 results in 280.  Then implement that in code.  Ask here again if you need help with your code.

Comment: My problem is to find such a mathematical function, to implement it is no problem, but I can't think of a suitable function.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example would be the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double start = 10;
        double end = 280;
        int numberOfNumbers = 100;

        double[] list = new double[numberOfNumbers];
        list[numberOfNumbers - 1] = end;

        for (int i = 2; i < numberOfNumbers; ++i) {
            list[numberOfNumbers - i] = list[numberOfNumbers - (i - 1)] - (1.0/(numberOfNumbers - i));
        }

        list[0] = start;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

Output would be something like
`10, 274.83272349246164, 275.83272349246164, ..., 279.97948664001683, 279.98979591836735, 280`

If you have numbers not that far apart, you need to choose a function that converges faster to 0 than 1/n like 1/(n^2) or 1/(2*n)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
    double[] result = new double[100];
    result[0] = start;
    result[99] = 280;

    for (int i = 1; i < 99; i++) {
        result[i] = result[i - 1] + (280 - result[i - 1]) / 21.0;
    }
```

result:
[10.0, 22.857142857142858, 35.102040816326536, 46.76384839650146, 57.870331806191864, 68.44793505351606, 78.52184290811053, 88.11604086486717, 97.25337225225445, 105.95559262119471, 114.24342154399497, 122.13659194666188, 129.65389709205894, 136.81323532577042, 143.63165269120992, 150.12538351543802, 156.30988906232193, 162.19989434506851, 167.80942318577954, 173.15183160550433, 178.23983962428983, 183.0855615469427, 187.7005348066121, 192.09574743486866, 196.28166422368443, 200.26825164160422, 204.0650015634326, 207.6809538699358, 211.12471797136743, 214.4044933060642, 217.5280888629183, 220.50294177420793, 223.33613502305516, 226.0344143076716, 228.60420410254437, 231.05162295480417, 233.38249805219445, 235.60237909732805, 237.71655152126482, 239.73004906787125, 241.647665778925, 243.4739674085, 245.2133022938095, 246.86981170839002, 248.44743972227621, 249.94994259264402, 251.38089770728, 252.74371210217143, 254.0416305734966, 255.2777434033301, 256.4549937174572, 257.5761844928164, 258.64398523125374, 259.66093831547977, 260.6294650623617, 261.5518714879635, 262.4303537980605, 263.26700361720043, 264.0638129687623, 264.82267901786884, 265.5454085884465, 266.23372246518716, 266.8892594906544, 267.5135804672899, 268.1081718736094, 268.67444940343756, 269.2137613366072, 269.7273917491497, 270.2165635706188, 270.68244149582745, 271.1261347579309, 271.54869976945804, 271.9511426375791, 272.33442155959915, 272.69944910438016, 273.04709438512396, 273.3781851286895, 273.69350964637096, 273.9938187108295, 274.2798273436471, 274.5522165177592, 274.81163477881825, 275.0586997893507, 275.29399979938165, 275.51809504703016, 275.73151909240966, 275.9347800880092, 276.1283619885802, 276.3127257034097, 276.4883101937235, 276.65553351783194, 276.8147938265066, 276.9664703109587, 277.11092410567494, 277.2484991482618, 277.3795229983446, 277.50430761747106, 277.6231501118772, 277.736333439883, 280.0]

Comment: But then the end is not with decreasing increment `result[99] - result[98] > result[98] - result[97]`

Comment: As I wrote: 2 bay be to small. Using 43 gives distinct numbers. and changing the array type to a floating point type make it smoother.